# CSS display grid hover border colour change

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking to create a simple table with the look below. I'm having difficulty changing the border of the row to red when it is being hovered over ... as long as the row is not the header row. So if it has a class of **"grid headers-row"** then nothing occurs when you hover over it. However for a data row, ie class is **"grid"** the entire row border (seen in black) will change it's border color to red.

[image]

I'm trying within this css/html context

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 10% 25% 25% 25%;
  > * {
    height: 5.125rem;
    text-align: left;
    &:first-child {
      border-radius: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    &:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
    }
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  &:not(.headers-row) > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: center;
    &:first-child {
      justify-content: center;
    }
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    &:first-child {
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid headers-row">
  <span>Name</span>
  <span>Age</span>
  <span>Address</span>
  <span>Status</span>
  <span>QRSCode</span>
 </div>
 <div class="grid">
  <span>
   <div>John Doe</div>
   <div>jdoe@jdoe.com</div>
  </span>
  <span>67</span>
  <span>
     <div>Address 1</div>
     <div>Address 2</div>
  </span>
  <span><div>Status</div></span>
  <span><div>1234567</div></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am editing to correct the last span and div tag interchange and added the forgotten closing div

Comment: Your code has several errors. Please put it thro' a validator e.g. https://validator.w3.org then correct it in the question and create a snippet that we can run to see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: Apologies for oversight, thanks Mehdi

Comment: You very welcome Fred2020

Comment: Your code still has several errors (span as parent of div). Please correct it, although as your data is actually tabular it should be in an HTML table for better sematics (especially as an aid to accessibility).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is just a different border color then add a rule that changes a `border-color` of nested elements when the row is `:hover`ed

```css
.grid {
  &:not(.headers-row):hover > * {
    border-color: red;
  }
}
```

Snippet with plain CSS:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 10% 25% 25% 25%
}

.grid>* {
  height: 5.125rem;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem
}

.grid>*:first-child {
  border-radius: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 1rem
}

.grid>*:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0
}

.grid:not(.headers-row)>* {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0
}

.grid:not(.headers-row)>*:first-child {
  justify-content: center
}

.grid:not(.headers-row)>*:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black
}

.grid:not(.headers-row)>*:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black
}

.grid:not(.headers-row):hover>* {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="grid headers-row">
  <span>Name</span>
  <span>Age</span>
  <span>Address</span>
  <span>Status</span>
  <span>QRSCode</span>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <span>
   <div>John Doe</div>
   <div>jdoe@jdoe.com</div>
  </span>
  <span>67</span>
  <span>
     <div>Address 1</div>
     <div>Address 2</div>
  </span>
  <span><div>Status</div></span>
  <span><div>1234567</div></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `&:not(.headers-row):hover >` * selector and define its border properties within.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 10% 25% 25% 25%;
  > * {
    height: 5.125rem;
    text-align: left;
    &:first-child {
      border-radius: 0.5rem 0 0 0.5rem;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 1rem;
    }

    &:last-child {
      border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0;
    }
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  &:not(.headers-row) > * {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: center;
    &:first-child {
      justify-content: center;
    }
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    &:first-child {
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
  }
  &:not(.headers-row):hover > * {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    &:first-child {
      border-left: 1px solid red;
    }
    &:last-child {
      border-right: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid headers-row">
  <span>Name</span>
  <span>Age</span>
  <span>Address</span>
  <span>Status</span>
  <span>QRSCode</span>
 </div>
 <div class="grid">
  <span>
   <div>John Doe</div>
   <div>jdoe@jdoe.com</div>
  </span>
  <span>67</span>
  <span>
     <div>Address 1</div>
     <div>Address 2</div>
  </span>
  <span><div>Status</div></span>
  <span><div>1234567</div></span>
</div>
```